# Bundle and Deploy my nodejs program as an executable

Tags: node.js, deployment, bundle, executable, distribute

I have a program written with `node js` that I want to bundle and distribute as "stand-alone" executable program.

I want to run the program through `cmd` only with the the executable file name (without using `npm run start` or `node file.js`). i.e. `my_program arguments`.

What is the most recommended way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are several options you can choose from. I would recommend checking out [Pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg).

With Pkg, you can package your node application into a single executable for Windows, Linux or Mac.

Simply install Pkg globally on your machine by running the command:

```
npm install -g pkg
```

and then add your point of entry to the package.json file as shown below:

```
{
   "bin": "bin.js" // or whatever your point of entry is
}
```

Afterwards, from your app directory simply run the command

```
pkg .
```

This would build the executables for Windows, Linux and MacOS.

You can execute the executable by running:

Windows: `your_exec-win.exe # windows`

Linux: `chmod u+x your_exec-linux; ./your_exec-linux`